# Having trouble to OnMouseDrag object on x axis while constantly moving it on z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first ever stack question so any help will be appreciated, a lot.

I'm looking for a specific movement for my player object. I want it to move on z-axis constantly but also I want to move it with my mouse on the x-axis. With the code I have player moves on z-axis but it doesn't on x-axis with my mouse input.

Tried LOTS OF variations of codes for what I want but other than keyboard "horizontal" input nothing worked and that's not what I want. Here's the code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PickerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float velocity = 1f;

    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private float _objXPos;
    private float _movX;
    private void Awake()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _objXPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).x;
        Debug.Log("pressing mouse");
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        var mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePoint.x = _objXPos;
        _movX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint).x;
        Debug.Log("dragging mouse");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var z = (velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime)*5;
        var newPos = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, z);
        if (_movX > 0.9f)
            newPos.x = 0.9f;
        else if (_movX < -1.9f)
            newPos.x = -1.9f;
        else
            newPos.x = _movX;
        _rb.MovePosition(newPos);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're really just looking for the difference between the game object's x position and the mouse x position, but you keep setting the mouse x position EQUAL to the object's x position and then nothing is happening. Instead of:

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePoint.x = _objXPos;
    _movX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint).x;
    Debug.Log("dragging mouse");
}
```

Try just taking the difference between the mouse x, after converting to world point, and the object x:

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
    _movX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint).x - _objXPos;
    Debug.Log("dragging mouse");
}
```

Comment: Hey! First of all thank you for giving your valuable time to this. Really appreciated. I tried the code you written but the moment I click on the object with mouse it jumps and fixes to the x=-1.9 point in the if states. I wrote those values to use as borders for my object. Any idea to fix that?

Comment: @FarukBayraktar - I used the values you provided in your code. If you want it to do something else then replace that line with whatever you want. You haven't explained the functionality you want so I don't know what to give you.